# Why does parallelization of panda dataframes (which I manipulate using apply()) takes forever when using multiprocessing, and how to solve it?

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, apply, infinite

I have a very large panda dataframe (915000 rows) and two columns, and each row represents a newspaper article I have scraped (the entire database has around 2.5 gb). I have to manipulate it and read that parralelization could offer great gains. I first defined a function, add_features(df) which takes a dataframe and applies several transformations, returning the transformed dataframe. Apply() is used, and all other functions I created that I call in add_features(df) are written inside the function add_features.

To perform the parallelization process, I used the following code (which can be found in https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-own-super-pandas-using-multiproc-1c04f41944a1 and in several other stackoverflow pages):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool #for parallelization
#importing other conventional packages

def add_features(df)
    #several functions being created
    #apply() being used on several columns of the dataframe, using functions previously created
    #return (df)

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=4):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

transformed_df = parallelize_dataframe(toy_df, add_features)
```

where toy_df is a very small subset (100 rows) of my originally large database.

When I apply add_features() on toy_df, I get all results I desire. However, when I perform the code above, it never stops running. I read a few other questions, the answers to which recommended me to write add_features() in a py file and import it. I did that, checked if the imported function was working on toy_df (it was), but when I performed the code above (except for the part where I define add_features, as I actually imported it using from add_features_file import *, add_features_file.py being the file in which I defined the function), I also faced the same problem.

What I want is to simply be able to use this function to clean my dataframe through the parallelization process, basically how to avoid it lasting forever.

EDIT: I was asked to write the code behind the function add_features(x), but my main concern is with the parralelization process, as the function add_features works (I have tested it on a subset of my dataframe). The dataframe contains newspaper articles, the dates in which they were released, as well as website links.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day_dates': ['09/04/2020', '09/04/2020', '09/04/2020'], 
                   'day_everything': ["Petrobrás diz que 53 trabalhadores de plataforma entraram em greve. Estado é de tensão.", "CNI e centrais sindicais podem acompanhar ação judicial. Ainda há dúvidas sobre prazo.", "Bancos públicos e privados negociam empréstimo. Prazo médio está sendo negociado."],'day_links': [link_1, link_2, link_3]})
```

The function of interest is quite large. For the most part I am defining individual functions inside of it, and in the end I use these individual functions in the pandas.apply() method to generate the final dataframe of interest. I did it this way because, when I defined the intermediate functions and then defined another one consisting of the apply method (which use the intermediate functions in single rows), there was a problem with local/implicitly global variables such that the parralelization part wouldn`t even run ("name is not defined error" would arise when intermediate functions were called by the add_features functions, and were not defined inside of it). Thus I wrote all the intermediate functions inside the add_features function, the final chunck of which is effectively applied over the dataframe and performs textual transformations.

```
def add_features(df):
    
    def at_least_one_lower_case(sentence):
        if sentence.isupper():
            return ''
        else:
            return sentence

    def no_dirty_expressions(article):

        #palavras contendo partes abaixo sao completamente removidas
        palavras_a_tirar_caso_contenham=['-----------------------------------------------------------------','---------------------------------------------------------------','--------------------------------------------------------','-------------------------------------------------------','--------------------------------------------','------------------------------------------','------------------------------------','segunda-feira','terça-feira','quarta-feira','quinta-feira','sexta-feira','2ª-feira','3ª-feira','4ª-feira','5ª-feira','6ª-feira','2.ª','3.ª','4.ª','5.ª','6.ªs','6.ª','sábado','domingo','janeiro','fevereiro','março','abril','maio','junho','julho','agosto','setembro','outubro','novembro','dezembro','jan','fev','mar','abr','mai','jun','jul','ago','set','out','nov','dez','http','www.','quadrissemana','**','0-ações','2ª-feiraA','semestreAtuais','@','e-mail',] 
        #https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/negocios,iea-preco-agricola-sobe-1-87-na-terceira-semana-de-novembro,20041122p1280 https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,taxas-cobradas-por-fundos-diminuem-ganhos,20021003p13232  https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,saldo-em-conta-corrente-fica-em-us-725-milhoes-em-fevereiro,20060321p34175 
        palavras_a_tirar_caso_contenham_higher=[word.capitalize() for word in palavras_a_tirar_caso_contenham]
        palavras_a_tirar_caso_contenham=list(set(palavras_a_tirar_caso_contenham+palavras_a_tirar_caso_contenham_higher))
        pattern= ['/'] #colocar \u00C0-\u00FF depois de letras pra accent insensitivity #caso eu queira tirar algo especifico da palavra, mas nao elimina-la
        combined_pattern = r'|'.join(pattern)

        #palavras abaixo sao tiradas pontualmente de frases
        palavras_soltas_a_tirar=['--leia mais em','ler mais na pág','leia também','Leia Também','leia o especial','Leia o especial','Leia também','Leia Também', 'leia o','Leia o','(cotação)','(variação)','CORREÇÃO (OFICIAL)','CORREÇÃO(OFICIAL)', 'Este texto foi atualizado às']
        palavras_soltas_a_tirar_higher=[word.capitalize() for word in palavras_soltas_a_tirar]
        palavras_soltas_a_tirar=list(set(palavras_soltas_a_tirar+palavras_soltas_a_tirar_higher))

        #Ultima frase que contëm expressoes abaixo sera eliminada
        bad_last_sentences=['(com','(Por','(por','Por','por','colaborou', 'Colaborou', 'COLABORARAM', 'colaboraram','CONFIRA','Confira','confira','Não deixe de ver','veja abaixo as cotações de fechamento','*', '(Edição de','Este texto foi atualizado às','As informações são da Dow Jones','É proibido todo tipo de reprodução sem autorização por escrito do The New York Times']
        bad_last_sentences_higher=[word.capitalize() for word in bad_last_sentences]
        bad_last_sentences=list(set(bad_last_sentences+bad_last_sentences_higher))

        #Frases que contëm expressoes abaixo serao eliminadas
        bad_expressions=['TRADUÇÃO DE','Matéria alterada','matéria foi atualizada','Reportagem de','reportagem de','as informações são da Dow Jones','as informações são do jornal','BBC Brasil - Todos os direitos reservados','é proibido todo tipo de reprodução sem autorização por escrito da BBC','as informações são da Dow Jones','DOW JONES NEWSWIRES','CONFIRA','Confira','confira','não deixe de ver','veja abaixo as cotações de fechamento','telefones das lojas','veja abaixo o','Veja, abaixo, tabela','semestreAtuais','industrialAnoVagas','VarejoGrupoFevereiro','Ibovespa19951996199719981999200020012002','5319,5Ibovespa-1']
        bad_expressions_higher=[word.capitalize() for word in bad_expressions]
        bad_expressions=list(set(bad_expressions+bad_expressions_higher))

        article=article.strip() #garantindo que nao ha excesso de espaco nas bordas
        if article[-1] != '.': #garantindo que ultimo caractere eh ponto final
            article=article+'.'

        #tiro palavras sujas e que podem conter ponto ou virgula ou dois pontos ou exclamacao ou interrogacao. Faco isso agora pois se nao, corro o risco de criar mais palavras sujas na parte de correct_error()
        pre_token=article.split()
        replaced_token=[re.sub(combined_pattern,'', word) for word in pre_token if not any (symbol in word for symbol in palavras_a_tirar_caso_contenham)]
        article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_sujeira=' '.join(replaced_token)

        #tiro palavras soltas de dentro de sentences
        def palavras_soltas_a_tirar_fun(sentence):
            for sujeira in palavras_soltas_a_tirar:
                if sujeira in sentence:
                    sentence=sentence.replace(sujeira,'')
            return (sentence)
        sentences=article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_sujeira.split('.')
        replaced_sentences=[palavras_soltas_a_tirar_fun(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
        article_sem_palavras_soltas='.'.join(replaced_sentences)

        #tiro palavras sujas identificaveis via regex pertencendo a estas palavras, ao inves de uma substring pertencendo a elas
        def fun_remove_exact_regex(word):
            exact_regex= [r'[0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{4}']
            for pat in exact_regex:    
                if not re.search(pat,word):
                    return(word)
                else:
                    return ''
        pre_token_2=article_sem_palavras_soltas.split()
        replaced_token_2=[fun_remove_exact_regex(word) for word in pre_token_2 ]
        article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex=' '.join(replaced_token_2)    

        article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex=article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex.strip() #garantindo que nao ha excesso de espaco nas bordas
        if article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex[-1] != '.': #garantindo que ultimo caractere eh ponto final
            article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex=article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex+'.'    
        #tiro a última frase caso esta seja suja
        sentences=article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex.split('.')
        last_sentence=article_sem_palavras_que_contenham_exact_regex.split('.')[-2]
        no_dirty_last_sentence=sentences[:-2] if any (bad_last_sentence in last_sentence for bad_last_sentence in bad_last_sentences) else sentences
        no_dirty_last_sentence='.'.join(no_dirty_last_sentence)

        #tiro alguma frase suja central restante
        sentences=no_dirty_last_sentence.split('.')
        clean_sentences=[sentence for sentence in sentences if not any(expression in sentence for expression in bad_expressions)]
        not_upper_clean_sentences=[at_least_one_lower_case(sentence) for sentence in clean_sentences]
        clean_text='.'.join(not_upper_clean_sentences)

        return clean_text

    def fun_split(text):
        return text.split()

    def at_least_one_letter(word):
        if any(character.isalpha() for character in word):
            return word
        else:
            return ''

    def fun_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols(list_of_tokens):
        bad_symbols=['#','$'] #o ultimo elemento engloba tokens formados por letras maisculas dentro de parentesis, como (PIB). Eu perderia (PIB) no caminho, mas tudo bem desde que esteja depois de produto interno bruto. PIB solto eu não perco. Faco isso pq mts vezes tem tags de acoes da bovespa escritos dessa forma. Eu antes substituia isso por espacos vazios, dessa forma acabava tendo uma porrada de palavras vazias. agora elimino tokens assim por completo (e dificilmente uma palavra normal contera nela parenthesis com letras maiusculas, a nao ser q esquecao o espaco)
        pattern=[''] #colocar \u00C0-\u00FF depois das letras pra accent insensititity#r'\([A-Z]+?\)'   decidi nao eliminar palavras como (PIB)
        combined_pattern = r'|'.join(pattern)
        clean=[re.sub(combined_pattern,'',at_least_one_letter(word)) for word in list_of_tokens if not any(symbol in word for symbol in bad_symbols)]
        return clean

    def fun_clean_extreme(list_of_tokens):

        def clean_extreme(word):                                                                                                                                                                   
            if any(character.isalnum() for character in word):
                while not (word[0].isalnum()):
                    word=word[1:]
                while not (word[-1].isalnum()):
                    word=word[:-1]
                return (word)
            else: #Pois se nao levasse em conta tokens nao alfanumericos, daria problema
                return ''     
        clean=[clean_extreme(word) for word in list_of_tokens]

        return clean

    def flatten_list(_2d_list):
        flat_list = []
       # Iterate through the outer list
        for element in _2d_list:
            if type(element) is list:
               # If the element is of type list, iterate through the sublist
                for item in element:
                    flat_list.append(item)
            else:
                flat_list.append(element)
        return flat_list        

    def no_initial_repetition_of_vowel(word): #perderei siglas neste passo
        if len(word)>=2 and word not in ['Aaabar','Aaa.br','Aa3.br']: 
            if (word[0]=='A' and word[1]=='A') or (word[0]=='A' and word[1]=='a') or (word[0]=='a' and word[1]=='A') or (word[0]=='a' and word[1]=='a'):
                index=1
                splitat= index
                l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat:]
                return [l,r]
            else:
                return(word)
        else:
            return(word)


    def correct_dot(word):
        if '.' in word:
            index=word.find('.') #vai estar no meio
            if word[index+1].isupper():        
                splitat= index
                l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
                return [l,r]
            else:
                return(word)
        else:
            return(word)

    def correct_comma(word):

        if ',' in word:
            index=word.find(',') #vai estar no meio
            splitat= index
            l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
            return [l,r]
        else:
            return(word)

    def correct_comma_dot(word):

        if ';' in word:
            index=word.find(';') #vai estar no meio
            splitat= index
            l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
            return [l,r]
        else:
            return(word)

    def correct_exclamation(word):

        if '!' in word:
            index=word.find('!') #vai estar no meio
            splitat= index
            l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
            return [l,r]
        else:
            return(word)

    def correct_question_mark(word):

        if '?' in word:
            index=word.find('?') #vai estar no meio
            splitat= index
            l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
            return [l,r]
        else:
            return(word)    

    def correct_two_dots(word):

        if ':' in word:
            index=word.find(':') #vai estar no meio
            splitat= index
            l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
            return [l,r]
        else:
            return(word)    

    def no_two_hifens(word):  #nao quero '2000--tesouro' #assumo que mais hifens alem de dois entre palavras pode ser sujeira de tabela
        pattern=r'^.*[0-9]*[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]*.*[-]{2}.*[0-9]*[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]*.*[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]*$' #pra accent insensitivy
        if re.match(pattern,word): 
            index=word.find('--') 
            splitat= index
            l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+2:]
            return [l,r]
        else:
            return(word)        

    def single_hifen_exception(word):    
        special_list=['19,5%-Unica','13,7%-Anfavea','6,22%-IBGE']    
        if word in special_list:
            index=word.find('-') 
            splitat= index
            l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
            return [r]
        else:
            return(word)    

    def correct_error(article):
        article=flatten_list([no_initial_repetition_of_vowel(word) for word in article])
        article=flatten_list([correct_dot(word) for word in article])
        article=flatten_list([correct_comma(word) for word in article])    
        article=flatten_list([correct_two_dots(word) for word in article])
        article=flatten_list([correct_exclamation(word) for word in article])
        article=flatten_list([correct_question_mark(word) for word in article])
        article=flatten_list([no_initial_repetition_of_vowel(word) for word in article])
        article=flatten_list([no_two_hifens(word) for word in article])
        article=flatten_list([single_hifen_exception(word) for word in article])


        return article

    def fun_no_symbols_except_hyphens_replaced_without_space(list_of_tokens):
        patterns=[r'[^ \nA-Za-z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ-/]+'] #\u00C0-\u00FF
        combined_pattern = r'|'.join(patterns)
        clean=[re.sub(combined_pattern, '', word) for word in list_of_tokens]
        return clean

    def fun_no_spaces_in_middle(list_of_tokens):
        clean=flatten_list([word.split() for word in list_of_tokens])
        return clean        



    def fun_not_the_same_character(list_of_tokens):
        def not_the_same_character(word):
            if len(word)>=2:
                if word == len(word) * word[0]:
                    return ''
                else: 
                    return word    
            else:
                return ''    
        clean=[not_the_same_character(word) for word in list_of_tokens]
        return clean

 
    #ELIMINATING CERTAIN VOCALUBARY    

    def fun_sep_letters_and_numb_hifen(list_of_tokens):
        def separate_right_letters_from_left_numbers_when_hifen(word):
            pat_numbers_before_letters_hifen=r'^[0-9]+[-]{1}[0-9]*[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]+$' #damos espaco para hifen. por exemplo, 145paises-membros  viraria paises-membros. A regra so vale se o numero NAO eh seguido de hifen. Faco isso pois assumo que neste caso pode ter havido uma falta de espaco do jornal. Posso inclusive botar isso mais no inicio   
            if re.match(pat_numbers_before_letters_hifen,word):        
                index=word.find('-') 
                splitat= index
                l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat+1:]
                return r
            else:
                return word
        def separate_left_letters_from_right_numbers_when_hifen(word):
            pat_letters_before_numbers_hifen=r'^[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]+[-]{1}[0-9]+$'   #o hifen nao pode estar colado na letra, pois caso contrario perderiamos covid-19 so para covid, o que nao eh de todo pior.  
            if re.match(pat_letters_before_numbers_hifen,word) and word not in ['covid-19','Covid-19']:    
                index=word.find('-') 
                splitat= index
                l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat:]
                return l
            else:
                return word

        clean=[separate_right_letters_from_left_numbers_when_hifen(separate_left_letters_from_right_numbers_when_hifen(word)) for word in list_of_tokens]
        return clean

    def sep_letter_and_numb(list_of_tokens):

        def separate_right_letters_from_left_numbers(word):
            pat_numbers_before_letters=r'^[0-9]+[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]*[-]*[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]+$' #damos espaco para hifen. por exemplo, 145paises-membros  viraria paises-membros. A regra so vale se o numero NAO eh seguido de hifen. Faco isso pois assumo que neste caso pode ter havido uma falta de espaco do jornal. Posso inclusive botar isso mais no inicio   
            if re.match(pat_numbers_before_letters,word):        
                index=word.find(next(filter(str.isalpha,word))) 
                splitat= index
                l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat:]
                return r
            else:
                return word
        def separate_left_letters_from_right_numbers(word):
            pat_letters_before_numbers=r'^[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]+[0-9]*[0-9]+$'   #o hifen nao pode estar colado na letra, pois caso contrario perderiamos covid-19 so para covid, o que nao eh de todo pior.  
            if re.match(pat_letters_before_numbers,word) and word not in ['G20','G8']:        
                index=word.find(next(filter(str.isnumeric,word))) 
                splitat= index
                l, r = word[:splitat], word[splitat:]
                return l
            else:
                return word  

        clean=[separate_left_letters_from_right_numbers(separate_right_letters_from_left_numbers(word)) for word in list_of_tokens]
        return clean

    def fun_no_letters_surrounded_by_numbers(list_of_tokens):
        patterns=[r'[0-9]+[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]+[0-9]+[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00FF]*']
        combined_pattern = r'|'.join(patterns)
        clean=[word for word in list_of_tokens if not re.match(combined_pattern,word)]
        return clean

    def fun_no_single_character_token(list_of_tokens):
        clean=[word for word in list_of_tokens if len(word) > 2] 
        return clean

    def fun_no_stopwords(list_of_tokens):

        nltk_stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('portuguese') #é uma lista
        personal_stopwords = ['Esse','Essa','Essas','Esses','De','A','As','O','Os','Em','Também','Um','Uma','Uns','Umas','Eu','eu','Ele','ele','Nós','nós','Você','você','entanto','Entanto','ser','Ser','com','Com','como','Como','se','Se','portanto','Portanto','Enquanto','enquanto','No','no','Na','na','Nessa','Nesse','Nesses','Nessas','As','A','Os','às','Às','ante','Ante','entre','Entre','sim','não','Sim','Não','Onde','onde','Aonde','aonde','após','Após','ser','Ser','hoje','Se','vai','Hoje','Por','Quando','Também','Depois','Mesmo','Numa','Numas','Pelos','Aquele','Aquela','Aqueles','Aquelas','Aquilos','Há','Ou','Isso','Segundo','segundo','pois','Pois','outro','Outro','outros','Outros','outra','Outras','outras','Outra','Este','cada','Cada','para','Para','disso','Disso','dessa','desse','deste','desta','Deste','Desta','Destes','Destas','já','Já','Mas','mas','ao','Ao','porém','Porém','Este','mesma','Mais','cujo','cuja','cujos','cujas','caso','quanto','a partir','cujo','caso','quanto','devido','pelo','pela','pelas','à','do','disto','mesmas','mesmos','nós','primeiro','primeiros','primeira','primeiras','segunda','quanto','neste','nesta','nestes','nestas']
        list_of_numbers=list(range(0, 100))
        lista_numeros_extenso=[num2words(number,lang='pt_BR') for number in list_of_numbers]
        initial_stopwords=nltk_stopwords+personal_stopwords+lista_numeros_extenso
        initial_stopwords_lower=[word.lower() for word in initial_stopwords]
        exceptions=['são','fora'] #Assim, preservamos 'São Paulo' e 'Fora Temer'
        initial_stopwords_higher=[word.capitalize() for word in initial_stopwords_lower if not word in exceptions]
        stopwords=list(set(initial_stopwords_lower+initial_stopwords_higher))
        stopwords.sort()
        clean=[word for word in list_of_tokens if word not in stopwords]
        return clean
    
    #Lematizing and _lower_case
    ! python -m spacy download pt_core_news_sm
    nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm") #, disable=['parser', 'ner'] # just keep tagger for lemmatization
    def fun_verb_lematized_lower_case(list_of_tokens):
        #nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm") #, disable=['parser', 'ner'] # just keep tagger for lemmatization
        spacy_object=nlp(' '.join(list_of_tokens))
        clean=[token.lemma_.lower() if token.pos_=='VERB' else token.text.lower() for token in spacy_object]
        return clean

    def fun_verb_adv_adj_pron_det_lematized_lower_case(list_of_tokens):   
        #nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm") #, disable=['parser', 'ner'] # just keep tagger for lemmatization
        spacy_object=nlp(' '.join(list_of_tokens))
        clean=[token.lemma_.lower() if (token.pos_=='VERB' or token.pos_== 'ADV' or token.pos_== 'ADJ' or token.pos_== 'DET' or token.pos_== 'PRON') else token.text.lower() for token in spacy_object]
        return clean

    def fun_completely_lematized_lower_case(list_of_tokens):   
        #nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm") #, disable=['parser', 'ner'] # just keep tagger for lemmatization
        spacy_object=nlp(' '.join(list_of_tokens))
        clean=[token.lemma_.lower() for token in spacy_object]
        return clean    

    def function_unique_tokens(text):
        clean=set(text)
        return clean
            
    print ('no_dirty_expression')
    df['no_dirty_expression']=df['everything'].apply(lambda x: no_dirty_expressions(x))
    print ('tokenized')
    df['tokenized']=df['no_dirty_expression'].apply(lambda x: fun_split(x))
    print ('no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols')
    df['no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols']=df['tokenized'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols(x))
    print ('no_symbols_in_extreme')
    df['no_symbols_in_extreme']=df['no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: fun_clean_extreme(x))
    print ('correction_errors')
    df['correction_errors']=df['no_symbols_in_extreme'].apply(lambda x: correct_error(x))
    print ('no_symbols_except_hyphens_replaced_without_space')
    df['no_symbols_except_hyphens_replaced_without_space']=df['correction_errors'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_symbols_except_hyphens_replaced_without_space(x))
    print ('no_symbols_in_extreme_again')
    df['no_symbols_in_extreme_again']=df['no_symbols_except_hyphens_replaced_without_space'].apply(lambda x: fun_clean_extreme(x))
    print ('no_spaces_in_middle')
    df['no_spaces_in_middle']=df['no_symbols_in_extreme_again'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_spaces_in_middle(x))
    print ('no_same_character_word')
    df['no_same_character_word']=df['no_spaces_in_middle'].apply(lambda x: fun_not_the_same_character(x))
    print ('again_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols')
    df['again_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols']=df['no_same_character_word'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols(x))
    print ('no_letters_and_numbers_divided_by_hyphen')
    df['no_letters_and_numbers_divided_by_hyphen']=df['again_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: fun_sep_letters_and_numb_hifen(x))
    print ('no_letters_and_numbers_glued')
    df['no_letters_and_numbers_glued']=df['no_letters_and_numbers_divided_by_hyphen'].apply(lambda x: sep_letter_and_numb(x))
    print ('no_letters_surrounded_by_numbers')
    df['no_letters_surrounded_by_numbers']=df['no_letters_and_numbers_glued'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_letters_surrounded_by_numbers(x))
    print ('no_single_character_token')
    df['no_single_character_token']=df['no_letters_surrounded_by_numbers'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_single_character_token(x))
    print ('no_stopwords')
    df['no_stopwords']=df['no_single_character_token'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_stopwords(x))
    print ('once_more_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols')
    df['once_more_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols']=df['no_stopwords'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols(x))
    print ('verb_lematized_lower_case')
    df['verb_lematized_lower_case']=df['once_more_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: fun_verb_lematized_lower_case(x))
    print ('verb_adv_adj_pron_det_lematized_lower_case')
    df['verb_adv_adj_pron_det_lematized_lower_case']=df['once_more_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: fun_verb_adv_adj_pron_det_lematized_lower_case(x))
    print ('completely_lematized_lower_case')
    df['completely_lematized_lower_case']=df['once_more_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: fun_completely_lematized_lower_case(x))
    print ('verb_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols')
    df['verb_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols']=df['verb_lematized_lower_case'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols(x))
    print ('all_but_noun_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols')
    df['all_but_noun_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols']=df['verb_adv_adj_pron_det_lematized_lower_case'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols(x))
    print ('complete_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols')
    df['complete_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols']=df['completely_lematized_lower_case'].apply(lambda x: fun_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols(x))
    print ('unique_verb_tokens')
    df['unique_verb_tokens']=df['verb_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: function_unique_tokens(x))
    print ('unique_all_but_nouns_tokens')
    df['unique_all_but_nouns_tokens']=df['all_but_noun_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: function_unique_tokens(x))
    print ('unique_all_tokens')
    df['unique_all_tokens']=df['complete_final_no_tokens_with_no_letters_and_bad_symbols'].apply(lambda x: function_unique_tokens(x))

    return df
```

Once again, my main concern, given also a lack of time for me to finnish my thesis, is to be able to perform the parralelization process with THIS function (though if I find some time, it will be a pleasure to try to make it more efficient). The only problem I have faced is that the parralelization chunck never stops running, although the function works and I have tested it on smaller dataframes.

Comment: Can you add some rows of your dataframe? and the full function? Seems there could be gains elsewhere possibly before getting into parallel processing. without data though, tough to help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok, I hope I made it more clear now. I had made the question longer after the first comment, but my goal is to perform parallelization with multiprocessing sucessfully